# Why Jquery each function stopped working?

Tags: jquery

This code of mine was working well, but now it has stopped working!! What might be wrong with it?
Am looping through table rows, using the JQuery .each function,

html:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/post_updates/" onSubmit="return postUpdates()" >
    <table id="mytable" class="table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>col 1</th>
             <th>col2 </th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       !-- rows are created dynamically --
       {% for object in object_list %}
         <tr>
          <td id="row">{{object.id}}</td>
          !-- other td's --
         </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function postUpdates(){
    $("#mytable tr:gt(0)").each( function () {
       // this code NEVER get executed
      var rowid = $(this).find("#row").html();
      // .. does alot of stuff with rowid!!
    });
  }
```

am sure this was working, but it just stopped. Tested it in both Chrome and Firefox!

Gath.

Comment: There quite a number of rows...

Comment: can we see the markup against which your code is run?

Comment: OK, you have multiple td elements with the same ID.  That needs to be corrected.  It sounds like that should be a class.  That is an invalid DOM and jQuery may just give up on that.

Comment: actually not... jquery will work with the first found element

Comment: Make sure that you are loading jquery and that it is at the path indicated. Also, always post your console logs; they contain vital information. (Press F12 for those; specifics vary by browser; Google is your friend!)

Answer (score 7):

you missed some parenthesis:

```
$("#mytable tr:gt(0)").each( function() {
   // this code NEVER get executed
  var rowid = $(this).find("row").html();
});
```

also your selector is missing something... I am assuming by your issue that the problem is before that, but `.find("row")` would not generally find something.

Comment: as said above   .find('row') will not get anything, if its an element with a class or id  use   .find('.row') or .find('#row')

Comment: what is the trigger event for this loop?  What is the DOM structure you are trying to examine?

Comment: even when the after changing .find("#row"), still nothing get executed. The problem is the .each() is not looping!!

Comment: if it is not looping, the problem exists outside the code you are posting.  Please update your question with more contextual information, like the container this snippet is in, and the DOM structure you are trying to loop through.

Comment: The trigger event, form onsubmit="return postUpdates()" inside the postUpdates function is where am calling the code.

Answer (score 5):

Missing parens:

```
$("#mytable tr:gt(0)").each( function() {
                                     ^^
```

**Update:** You are using the same `id` with multiple elements, which is not allowed. Change `id="row"` to `class="row"` and use the selector `.find(".row")` instead.

Comment: Well then, you should say what exactly "not working" means. For example, what is `$("#mytable tr:gt(0)").length`?

Comment: For my test i have three rows, .length returns 3

Comment: So the loop itself runs three times, right? You can check this by putting an `alert` as the first line in there. But it would be better if you gave us the relevant part of your HTML so we don't have to guess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3664/discussion-between-gath-and-jon)

Answer (score 0):

Below is how your markup should look after the scripting engine renders it. Notice the change in the onSubmit function and also the declaration of the function before it is invoked. As you are using jquery you should probably consider using their event binding api. In this case you should use [submit event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postUpdates(){
    $("#mytable tr:gt(0)").each( function () {
       // this code NEVER get executed
      alert( $(this).find("#row").html());
      // .. does alot of stuff with rowid!!
    });
  }
</script>
<form method="POST" action="" onSubmit="postUpdates()" >
    <table id="mytable" class="table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>col 1</th>
             <th>col2 </th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>


         <tr>
          <td id="row">test</td>
             <td>test2</td>
         </tr>

    </tbody>
   </table>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SSpwD/1/)